# NSFileManager doesn't create folder

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, nsfilemanager

```
- (NSURL *) applicationDocumentsDirectory
{
    return [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
}
```

....

```
NSURL *folder = [[[Database sharedInstance] applicationDocumentsDirectory] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"temp"];
BOOL isFolder;
NSLog(@"URL: %@", folder);
if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:folder.absoluteString isDirectory:&isFolder] == NO)
{
    NSLog(@"IsFolder: %d", isFolder);
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtURL:folder withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:&error];
    if (error)
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error.localizedDescription);
}
```

I run this part of code twice.

I expect that the folder will be created, but every time I receive a log: "IsFolder: 7".

Why the folder wasn't created after the first run?

Comment: make sure that isFolder is true

Comment: I have changed to: "BOOL isFolder = YES". fileExistsAtPath still returns NO...

Comment: try to use the `...AtPath:` instead of the `...AtURL:`, it might help you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Please, replace folder.absoluteString to folder, your problem will be solved.

Follow step by step:

1) Get documents folder

```
  NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentsDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
 NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
```

2) Get documents folder and folder name

```
NSString *dataPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"MyFolder"];
```

3) Check alerdy exists or not

```
if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:dataPath]){

    NSError* error;
    if(  [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:dataPath withIntermediateDirectories:NO attributes:nil error:&error])

        else
        {
            NSLog(@"[%@] ERROR: attempting to write create MyFolder directory", [self class]);
            NSAssert( FALSE, @"Failed to create directory maybe out of disk space?");
        }
```

Comment: Okay. I have changed withIntermediateDirectories: from YES to NO. On the second run I receive "The operation couldn’t be completed. File exists". It means that the file is created. I wonder why fileExistsAtPath returns NO each time?!

Answer (score 10):

The problem was in `folder.absoluteString`.

It should be `folder.path` instead.